# CDbCriteria param binding

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

On login page of YII application I have put following condition to validate user:

```
$criteria->condition = 'uname ILIKE :username OR email_id ILIKE :username';
$criteria->params = array(':username' => $this->username);
```

If i put backslah in username text field it throws an error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22025]: Invalid escape sequence: 7 ERROR: LIKE pattern must not end with escape character
```

I know there are many ways in php to remove slashes, I want to know is there any way in YII which will escape invalid character while binding with query.

I can write above condition in different way which will not give any problem

```
$criteria->compare('uname',$this->username,true,'OR');
$criteria->compare('email_id',$this->username,true,'OR');
```

But in that case It will build query with "LIKE" not with "ILIKE".

that's why i had to make proper use of $criteria->condition.

Comment: Take a step back from the code and explain what you're trying to accomplish here. Are you trying a case-insensitive equality match? Do you want to find if one string contains another, case insensitive? What is the purpose of using `like` not `=` here?

Comment: Yes i am trying to do insensitive match for email id and username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way of doing a case-insensitive match is `lower(email_id) = lower(:username)`. You can even create an expression index on `lower(email_id)` if you need an indexed lookup.

Alternately, use PostgreSQL's `citext` type.

`LIKE` and `ILIKE` are *pattern matching* operators that take *wildcard expressions*, not just literal strings. The reason you're getting an error on input like:

```
"pattern\"
```

is that a backslash in a `LIKE` expression escapes the next char (making a wildcard `_` or `%` into a literal `_` or `%`), so it's an error if there's no next char. To learn more, see [pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, with addSearchCondition and ILIKE

```
$criteria->addSearchCondition('uname',$this->username,true,'OR','ILIKE');
$criteria->addSearchCondition('email_id',$this->email_id,true,'OR','ILIKE');
```